# HTMLCollection vs NodeList

Tags: javascript, html, dom

cuando hacéis un

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')
```

os devuelve una lista de  **HTMLCollection**
y si haces un

```
document.querySelectorAll('div')
```

os devuelve una **lista de Nodes**.
¿Alguien sabe la diferencia? porque en principio me devuelve en una lista todos los DIVs del HTML

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer **NodeList** y **HTMLCollection** ambas son interficies de la colección de nodos del DOM. Básicamente se diferencian de los métodos que emplean para obtener el tipo de nodos. Mientras NodeList contiene todo tipo de nodos(de los doce tipos que hay), un HTMLCollection sólo contiene un tipo de nodos que son los nodos de elemento, es decir, las etiquetas html del documento.

Comment: La respuesta es más un comentario